# Is there a way to take symbols out of the tickerid in pinescript?

Tags: pine-script, ticker

I would apply this to Forex of course,
so for example if i had chart of AUDJPY and

```
A = security(tickerid, period, close)
```

is there a possibility take the "AUD" and "JPY" from tickerid and store them as separate variables?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `syminfo.basecurrency` and `syminfo.currency`.

Example script:

```
//@version=4
study("AUDJPY split", overlay=true)

if (barstate.islast)
    var1 = syminfo.basecurrency
    var2 = syminfo.currency
    myText = "First=" + var1 + "\nSecond=" + var2
    label.new(bar_index, high, text=myText)
    
plot(na)
```